# how do i prevent the horizontal scroll bar from showing up when a div extends past my content width?

Tags: html, css

I've seen this question asked a number of different ways but I just don't understand the answers because the application or scenario seems different than mine.

Basically I have a content width of 940px, and I want to use an 'easel' as a background for my slideshow, but the easel image extends about 400px PAST the content width of 940px, causing the horizontal scroll bar to show up at 940px + easel width (400px) - but i want the scrollbar to ONLY show up when the content is 940px or less - is there a simple fix im overlooking?

```
<div id="showcase">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="left">
                    <h1>Lidya Aaghia Tchakerian</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div id="slideshowArea">
                    <div id="slideshow">
                        <ul class="bjqs">
                            <li><img src="images/slider1.jpg" width="326" height="534" alt="" /></li>
                            <li><img src="images/slider1.jpg" width="326" height="534" alt="" /></li>
                            <li><img src="images/slider1.jpg" width="326" height="534" alt="" /></li>
                            <li><img src="images/slider1.jpg" width="326" height="534" alt="" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my css:

```
 /* showcase
------------------------------------------*/
#showcase {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
    height: 828px;
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

#showcase .left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 388px;
    top: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

#showcase .left  h1 {
    color: #cd6d6d;
}

#slideshowArea {    
    position: absolute;
    width: 824px;
    left: 495px;
    height: 875px;
    background: url('../images/easel.png') no-repeat;
}

#slideshow {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 72px;
    height: 534px;
    width: 326px;
    border: none;
    top: 107px;
}

#slideshow ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 326px;

}

ul .traits {
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
}

.traits li {
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding: 6px 0 0 22px;
    background: url('../images/checkbox.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Nathan

EDIT: to view the page visit http://www.digicrest.com/lidya

Comment: if i understand correctly, can't you just re-size the background image?

Comment: i dont think so - the background image has to be placed in an 'exact' spot with exact dimensions, which extends way past the content width of 940px.

Comment: if it's a static image you can resize it with a using a photo editor like PAINT.NET, if it's dynamic you can use the [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property on your css.

Comment: i dont understand how changing the image size is going to achieve anything..?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
#slideshowArea {    
  position: absolute;
  width: 824px;
  max-width: 940px;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Maybe overflow-y instead ?? */
  left: 495px;
  height: 875px;
  background: url('../images/easel.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I think I heard somewhere that IE8 needs -ms- prefix for overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm understanding this one of two ways:

1) If you want your #slideshow div to not have a scrollbar, you can set it's overflow property to 'hidden':

```
#slideshow {
display: block;
position: relative;
left: 72px;
height: 534px;
width: 326px;
border: none;
top: 107px;
overflow-x: hidden; /*ADD THIS*/
```

}

2) The other way I'm understanding this is that you have a div with background image of an easel that is supposed to 'hold' your #slideshow div, but that that background image is exceeding it's desired dimensions. One solution, if you're using a fixed design, is to make the background image to size of your container div, that way you know more or less where things are supposed to be.

Another solution is to use the CSS background-size property; if you want your background to be 940px wide, you can do:

```
 #container {
     background: url('directory/file.jpg');
     background-size: 940px auto;
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you are correct on #2

my content is 940px wide - there is some content on the left and a slideshow / holder on the right - i want the slideshow holder to have a background that extends past the 940px but so it doesn't cause the scroll bar to appear. right now the browser is thinking 940px + however much the easel background extends past that is the 'size' of the content.

I just want the browser to ignore the overhang.

Answer (score 1):

Using media queries you can specify the overflow attribute for your css element. It's not clear which id or class you want to target, so I've called it #your_id in the below example.

First for everything below 940px:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 940px) {
body {
overflow-x:visible;
}
}
```

Then for everything above 940px:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 940px) {
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
}
```

Find out more about @media queries here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/a/css3-media-queries.htm

Comment: im going to add a link to the site - maybe it will clear up any confusion:
http://www.digicrest.com/lidya

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I got the element. Try targeting the body element. So replace "#your_id" with "body" (without the quotes).

Comment: i tried this but doesn't seem to work... is there some special code i need to add the <head> tag for media query to work?

Comment: Where did you add the code? It should just go into your css file. Once you've added it there, and if it still doesn't work then let me know so I can inspect it.

Comment: You need to change #your_id to body. I've updated my answer so just copy it from there again.

Comment: oh woops , i didnt change it back before i uploaded - but yes i tried with body instead and it didn't work, uploaded the 'correct' css but still does not work...

Comment: It see it's being applied for the less than 940px, but it's not being applied to the more than 940px for some reason. Can you try removing "Then for everything above 940px:" which you've also copied into your css..